# How to load jersey endpoints from a jar in springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I have created a gradle spring-boot application which has both spring-mvc controllers as well as jersey jax-rs controllers. I have created .war file and deployed it in an external tomcat.

I am able to successfully hit spring-mvc controllers as well as jersey jax-rs endpoints which are part of the project. But when I try to hit endpoints which are part of jar file placed in **WEB-INF/lib** directory, I get 404 error response.

My **JerseyConfig** class file is as follows:

```
package com.example.core.config;

import com.example.core.rest.OauthController;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

public JerseyConfig(){
    packages("com.example.core.oauth.*");    //This the package I am trying to load from jar file
    property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
    register(OauthController.class);      //Endpoint created within the project which loads successfully

  }

}
```

When I call https://localhost/rest/oauthcontroller I get 200 response, even the spring mvc controller https://localhost/mycontroller from the same project gives 200 response, but all the rest endpoints which are part of the jar files(com.example.core.oauth.*) are giving 404 response.